# Should be Simple: How to preserve data on a page of basic javascript/css/html when going to another page

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

So that it isn't removed when we come back to the original page. This is just simple Javascript/HTML/CSS. We just want to preserve all the object states, and data in the original page.

Without using a database, preferably. I don't know much about that. Thanks!

Comment: Do you like cookies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you look into [localStorage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)